# Demonstrating that markets yield productive and allocative efficiency to introductory students

Tags: markets, competitive-equilibrium, efficient-markets

Has anybody come across a nice, intuitive (i.e. neither formal nor technical) way to demonstrate how markets yield both productive and allocative efficiency?

I suppose the allocative argument requires just a very superficial treatment of the first fundamental theorem, which is doable. But what about productive efficiency?

I'm teaching Econ 101 and I don't like the textbook's treatment of the topic -- it basically asserts efficiency without even trying to argue it.

Comment: What tools do you use in your class? Do you use indifference curves and Marginal Rate of Substitution? Would you consider a geometric treatment intuitive?

Comment: @denesp Yes, I use both of those. I even acknowledge the existence of derivatives (god forbid!), but I don't ask them to differentiate. But yes, most of how I'm teaching the class is geometric, so that would fit the bill perfectly.